# cordova filetransfer can not upload video in IOS

Tags: cordova

I use cordova 7.1, and I can upload images, audios in IOS and Android, but fail to upload video in IOS. 
from xcode debug console, I got message like these:

fileData length: 121096
File Transfer Finished with response code 200.

however, It's empty when I debug in the server. And anroid works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you **call another page** at the time of file upload then it will not work.
So try to call page transfer **using setTimeout().**

```
//======= Will working =======
function load(){
//Do your stuff...
uploadvideo();
setTimeout(function(){
window.location.replace("abc.html");
},6000); //6000 = 6000 milliseconds = 6 seconds
}

uploadvideo(){
 //call plugin
}


//======= Will not working =======
function load(){
//Do your stuff...
uploadvideo();
window.location.replace("abc.html");
}

uploadvideo(){
 //call plugin
}
```

Comment: Actually, I just upload the video and append a div with video control in it, the page will not be reloaded.

Comment: var captureVideoSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
        var file_path = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
        asyncReadFileAsBase64(file_path, function(base64_data, fs) {
            var id_postfix = new Date().getTime();
            var html = '<video controls="controls" id="video_'+id_postfix+'">';
            html += '<source src="'+ base64_data  +'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
            add_to_chat_box(id_postfix, html);
            asyncUpload(fs.toURL(), "video/mp4", null, null, null, function(percent) {
                //update progress
            });
        });
    };

Comment: var asyncUpload = function(file_path, mine_type, upload_option_setter, success_callback, error_callback, progress_callback) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file"; 
        options.fileName = file_path.substr(file_path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType = mine_type;
        //options.chunkedMode = false;

Answer (score 0):

Now, I used javascript to upload video in IOS, and it works well.